# Why Grafana does not include images to alerts?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

Have separately configured grafana image renderer, installed plugin and now can render any graphs.

But telegram alerts still without images and no any checkbox "Include image"

Grafana v8.4.6
Grafana Image Renderer v3.4.2

What should be configured else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since v9.0 is there a new way to take screenshots of panels.

1 - Create an alert from the panel, as always

2 - Setup alert

3 - Keep Dashboard UID and Panel ID annotations.

In v9.1 will be compatible with Telegram

More info in this discussion: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/38030

Official doc page: (with compatible notificators) https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/alerting/images-in-notifications/

Answer (score 0):

Image rendering was removed in grafana 8 alerts: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/discussions/38030

if you want images you have to go back to legacy alerts